# Set property of child control in template control of NumericUpDown control silverlight

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

This is my style for silverlight NumericUpDown control. I want to set TabIndex of  to Style of control .

```
 <Style x:Key="NumericUpdownStyle_Strength" TargetType="inputToolkit:NumericUpDown">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="50"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Minimum" Value="-28"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Maximum" Value="28"></Setter>            
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="DecimalPlaces" Value="2"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Increment" Value="0.25"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="inputToolkit:NumericUpDown">
                    <Grid>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>


                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" To="1"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>

                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Valid"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="InvalidUnfocused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="InvalidFocused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <sys:Boolean>True</sys:Boolean>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>

                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <inputToolkit:ButtonSpinner x:Name="Spinner" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="35">
                            <StackPanel Background="White" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="Auto">                                   
                                <TextBox x:Name="Text"  Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" TabIndex="0"
                                     BorderThickness="0" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontStretch="{TemplateBinding FontStretch}" FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" MinWidth="50" Width="Auto"  AcceptsReturn="False" Text="{TemplateBinding Value}" TextAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </inputToolkit:ButtonSpinner>
                        <Border x:Name="DisabledVisualElement" IsHitTestVisible="false" Opacity="0" Background="#A5FFFFFF" CornerRadius="2.5,2.5,2.5,2.5"/>
                        <Border x:Name="FocusVisualElement" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" BorderBrush="#FF45D6FA" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="1,1,1,1"/>
                        <Border x:Name="ValidationErrorElement" Visibility="Collapsed" BorderBrush="#FFDB000C" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="1">
                            <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                <ToolTip x:Name="validationTooltip" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Template="{StaticResource ValidationToolTipTemplate}" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Placement="Right" PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                                    <ToolTip.Triggers>
                                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Canvas.Loaded">
                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsHitTestVisible">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                <sys:Boolean>true</sys:Boolean>
                                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                        </EventTrigger>
                                    </ToolTip.Triggers>
                                </ToolTip>
                            </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                            <Grid Height="12" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="1,-4,-4,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="12" Background="Transparent">
                                <Path Fill="#FFDC000C" Margin="1,3,0,0" Data="M 1,0 L6,0 A 2,2 90 0 1 8,2 L8,7 z"/>
                                <Path Fill="#ffffff" Margin="1,3,0,0" Data="M 0,0 L2,0 L 8,6 L8,8"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

This is my XAML implementation of NumericUpDownControl

```
  <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource StackPanelStyle_LableValue}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ViewItem.Strength, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings }}" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}" />
                            <inputToolkit:NumericUpDown Style="{StaticResource NumericUpdownStyle_Strength}"
                                                        Value="{Binding RightSpecGlassStrength, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}" 
                                                        TabIndex="5" />
                        </StackPanel>
```

I want TabIndex property defined in the XAML implementation of NumericUpDown should be inherited in the "TextBox" defind in style of NumericUpDown Control.

Or

Is there any other way to assign Parents property to its child defined in the control template.
**i.e. TabIndex of NumericUpDown to Text box that is defined inside style if NumericUpDown**

How do I set it.??

Comment: TabIndex="{TemplateBidning TabIndex}" in control template worked for me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TemplateBinding` to bind the `TabIndex` of the `TextBox` to the `TabIndex` of the `NumericUpDown` control that contains it. Within your template simple add ...

```
<TextBox x:Name="Text" TabIndex="{TemplateBidning TabIndex}" ... />
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply... Yes I got it I set TabIndex="{TemplateBinding TabIndex}"